# What is best practice to hide parameters on url

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have some pages that is getting data from api with id which is passed from previous page. I could pass them like `url/5` or `url?id=5` but i dont want to do user able to see them on url bar. I searched for hide them and found 2 possible way. One of them is passing `skipLocationChange: true` in routing params and other one is creating an shared service but they have a common problem. When use them user become unable to refresh page. I'm not sure if storing id on local storage is a good way to do that, contolling it is scaring me. I hope you could help me to find a way. thank you for reading

Comment: as you're describing it, local storage is your only option, but if you want to facilitate refresh / sending URLs / storing URLs, you have to put them in the url.  you could theoretically encode them somehow and obscure them, but they'll still be in the URL in some form. you should ask yourself why you don't want them in the URL and make sure the reasoning is solid.

Comment: i think thats no big deal to show id on url but my manager asked me if i could hide it. i think i will encrypt them and let it stay on url bar. thank you for your response. but im open to other recommendations

Comment: if your manager is interested in "pretty" or seo friendly urls (which is valid), then sometimes a solution is creating slugs and using those in place of ids... a slug is like `what-is-best-practice-to-hide-parameters-on-url` part of this page's url... a human readable ID for the record.... but that is largely a server side implementation.... if manager is concerned about a security risk, then he is wrong as id's are trivial to obtain by opening your browser console.

Comment: Plenty sites uses some kind of ids in urls -- not sure why this can be bad. You can play with localstorage ofc, but that makes impossible to share such link.

Comment: thanks to you both for your answers.we decided to hide it from user and use shared service to pass id. user will be unable to refresh the page.

Comment: Hi, @Cem Kocagöz. I also suggest reading about `window.history.state` (https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state). You can use it like this: router.navigate('/url', { state: { id: 5 }) and in another component you can extract this date like this: this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state or window.history.state.

Comment: @AlexanderFSP thank you for your response, is that method has any difference between queryParams or shared service? i think i have to use locals storage any way

Comment: Yes, this data isn't visible for the user, because this state attaches to browser history and you can only programmatically extract this data. Also, it handles forward and backward navigation, but there is the same issue with page reload..

Comment: @AlexanderFSP i wish i was saw that before :( I think i solved the problem on harder way. I used shared service to pass data to other page and created an array and kept visited page on that array like [{page: 'pageA', id: 1}]. when user navigate to any page i add last page to this array. and when user pressed back button i delete last item from array. i hope next developer after me could forgive me

Comment: also started to using local storage to keep page id's to able refreshing